# What is the time complexity of this question?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

what is the time complexity of this code?

```
int count=0;

for(int I=N;I>0;I=I/2)

{

for(int j=0;j<I;j++)

   {

      count=count+1;

    }

}
```

Please explain it clearly

Comment: Can anyone give me suggestions,how to ask questions??what is the mistake in that question?Because whenever i ask a question,i got downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop does n iterations, then n/2, then n/4, etc.

```
i =n   n/2      n/4    n/8  ....................logn times

j=n     n/2     n/4    n/8 ...........logn tmes

T(n) = n+ n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...........logn time
       = n(1+ 1/2 + 1/4 + .............logn times) Decreasing GP
     =O(n)
```

Therefore,

> **The time complexity is `O(n)`**

To know more about Geometric series see this [document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Here lets take eg :

LET n = 10

initially: i  = 10 (first loop)

```
           j = 0 < 10(i) so it will loop from 0 to 9 times
```

NOW AFTER NESTED LOOP GETS OVER THIS TAKES PLACE

```
i /= 2
```

SO value of i = 5 (first loop ) 2 iteration.

this time j will run from     j = 0 < 5(i) so it will loop from 0 to 5 times

each time value of i will be divided by 2 and similarly for corresponding value of j will iterate from 0 to i/2 times.

so, `T(n) = O(n + n/2 + n/4 + … 1) = O(n)` for j (This is for iteration of j only )

```
i               j

10           0-9 times

5              0 - 4 times

2             0 - 1 times
```

similarly value of j which was initially n i.e 10  gets decreased in order on n/2 forming GP & thus we get **O(n)**

Comment: @Amit Nandal now are you able to resolve your issue??

Comment: What i understand is that time complexity for iteration of j is O(n) and time complexity for iteration of i is O(log n).Hence,the overall time complexity of this code is O(nl*og(n)).Am i correct or not???